# Which route is to write for same method on every page

Tags: php, laravel

Currenty developing a project in Laravel and want to now which route should I write when for example the search bar appears in the navigation bar on every page.
It would be great if I get any advice here.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? The navigation bar is frontend related. Routes are backend. If you just want to re-use the same navigation on every page, this would go into your view and probably use a partial. How do routes come into this? Are you merely trying to think of a name for a route?

Comment: If the user want to search for example for a customer than I have to use the controller and a method to get those data from the database... the question is which page name I have to give for the route .Route::post('/user', [UserController::class, 'getCustomer']);

Comment: It sounds like you're new to laravel and trying to understand how to set up the route and point it to a controller and method. You should first check your laravel version (if you run `php artisan` your laravel version will be at the top) then find the routing section in the manual corresponding to your laravel version: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing. If you use `Route::post` this expects an HTTP POST, such as the submitting of a form, or using Ajax. The clicking of a link would be an HTTP GET request. So you'd use `Route::get` for those. If you're not sure, you can use `Route::any`, etc.

Comment: The `'/user'` part would be what would appear in the browser. such as example.com/user. The UserController::class part should link to the controller class. You'd usually need a use statement at the top of the routes file `use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;` Then finally the `getCustomer` would be the method, i.e. the function within your controller class which would get called.

Comment: Thanks first of all. The problem is that the form appears on every page. Also on /dashboard or /settings.. it is in the navigation bar.

Comment: Forgive me for failing to understand what you're struggling on. You can send an extra parameter in your form as a hidden field, where you can specify which page the form is being submit from. You can then access the submitted data as part of the request from within your controller. See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests you can either let laravel inject `Request $request` as a parameter to the constructor or method being called, or you can use `$request = request()`. Once you have the request object, you can read the data send to the server. e.g. `$hello = $request->input('hello');`

Comment: Which page should I enter when the route exists on every page? Route::post('/user', [UserController::class, 'getCustomer']) or Route::post('/dashboard', [UserController::class, 'getCustomer'])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244328/discussion-between-kevin-y-and-jrwebdev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Johns answer was absolutely correct.

However I'll try to introduce you the basics in Laravel:

I assume you have a `layouts.blade.php` file in `resources\views\layouts` and its corresponding class in `app\View\Componets\AppLayout.php`

Or similar naming

1. your `app.blade.php` file in `resources\views\layouts` with the following content:

### app.blade.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Your Content goes here -->
<div>
    {{ $slot }}
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

### AppLayout.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class AppLayout extends Component
{
    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represents the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('layouts.app');
    }
}
```

This is your base Layout for any pages on your website

2. Create a route for your first page in your `routes\web.php` to view the new Layout

```php
Route::get('/page1',function (){
    return view('page1');
});
```

3. Create `page1.blade.php` in `resources\views`

### page1.blade.php:

```html
<x-index-layout>
    I'm Page One
</x-index-layout>
```

4. Create a new component for your search bar

```sh
php artisan make:component SearchBar
```

edit `resources/views/components/search-bar.blade.php` with something like this:

```html
<label for="search" title="Search">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
</label>
```

5. add the component to your `app.blade.php`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Search Bar -->

<x-search-bar/>

<!-- Your Content goes here -->
<div>
    {{ $slot }}
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

This will add your search bar on any page as long as you use the `<x-app-layout>` directive on other pages:

run it in the browser with `http://{your-url}/page1` you'll see `I'm Page One` with the search bar on top

1. Create a new file `page2.blade.php` in `resources\views` with the following content

```html
<x-app-layout>
    I'm Page Two
</x-app-layout>
```

2. Create its route:

```php
Route::get('/page2',function (){
    return view('page2');
});
```

3. run it in the browser with `http://{your-url}/page2` you'll see `I'm Page Two` with the search bar on top

Answer (score 0):

The default rendering engine Blade uses [layouts](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#building-layouts) for all the components of the site that are generic, you could add your search bar there.

An additional step would be to make the search bar a [component](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#components) and render it in the layout